# Installation on Acer Swift 5 freezes, no partitions are shown on Installation type screen

Tags: system-installation, bios, acer, acpi

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a brand new Acer Swift 5 (2019) using a USB flash drive. After the grub menu and the selection of keyboard, WiFi, etc., I get to the Installation type screen of the Ubuntu installer and there are no options there.

[image: see picture here]

Clicking on anything freezes the system and I have to restart by holding down the power button.

Error messages when trying Ubuntu from the USB flash drive:

[image]

Comment: Did you verify your ISO to ensure it was perfect after download? (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) and then validate the write to your install media to ensure it was flawless? (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck where CD refers to any install media, cd/dvd/hdd/ssd/thumb-drive/flash-card/..)

Comment: Thanks. The flash drive with iso was prepared by the it help desk where I work so I assume that they did it properly? Also, the flash drive works fine under "try Ubuntu" mode. Doesn't this mean that the ISO is fine?

Comment: The 'try ubuntu' doesn't verify the whole unless you used every option/application/etc, and verified for no squashfs errors in the logs & actually run the installer as well; no it means little (a single bit wrong can mean install shouldn't be trusted, try ubuntu won't have tested 100% of media).  The lack of install media in your picture could mean a kernel module (driver) is required to be added, but that's a waste of time until media has been verified; the freezing makes flawed media the more likely cause in my reading.

Comment: ps:  note I don't know your equipment so that is not taken into account in my 2c worth.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried "try Ubuntu" once more and saw that there were a few errors that went flashing by. I could only capture them on video although not very clear.
ACPI BIOS error (bug): could not resolve symbol...
ACPI error aborting method... 
*ERROR * discarding overwritten... 
See also the attached image in the edited original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was not the ISO or how the USB stick was prepared in Rufus. I had to change a few things in BIOS, namely:

- Changed BIOS to UEFI
- Disabled secureboot
- Set superuser password
- Changed SATA to AHCI mode. This was the trickiest part as the option was hidden in the BIOS menu. It became available by hitting ctrl-s once in the appropriate BIOS menu.