# Dual Boot System - SSD Having (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) showing as unknown device

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, ssd

**Laptop** : Acer  E5

**Primary** Drive: SSD (Ubuntu 18.04 Installed) 64bit

**Secondary** : HHD (Windows 10) 64bit

Boot Menu: Grub Gnu
I have set Under Windows the following "bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi"

It loads ubuntu by default, until select the windows 10,
It is working fine from months than

**Possible Cause of problem**

Yesterday, I logged into Ubuntu and did pressed the power button to shutdown the system.

After that I logged into Windows and did Update windows (maybe this cause the problem)

**Actual Problem**
After some time i again restarted the system and under Boot Screen

It is showing Grub error
"Minimal BASH like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions."

**Solutions Tried**:

I created Live Ubuntu USB

Boot from USB using try Ubuntu

And followed the Boot repair option but it is not showing the "recommended repair" option.

Boot-Repair summary
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gw8ZzfdY7V/

Also SSD Drive is neither showing nor detecting.

Under Disks it is showing SSD as (dev/sda) but against Partition (No Content)

Using Gparted it is showing unallocated all the disk space (I can't see the partitions, root or others

[screenshot of gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxL91.png)

sudo fdisk -l
[Ubuntu installed under /dev/sda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOJr0.jpg)

Still not showing devices/ partitions related to the sda (SSD in which Ubuntu Installed)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxL91.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOJr0.jpg]

I have tried all possible solutions, review the BIOS settings but still no luck

**Let me notedown the main points again**

1. Under Grub Boot (No device) instead of Ubuntu
2. why /dev/sda showing unallocated (where ubuntu installed)
3. Live Ubuntu USB even were unable to read the file

If i lost all the SSD data how to fix the SSD issue and Boot Loading issue ?

Comment: Did you use power switch to shutdown? That can cause data corruption so partition needs fsck if ext4 or chkdsk if Windows NTFS. Also Windows updates turn fast start up back on and may update UEFI changing UEFI settings back to defaults. First post link to Boot-Repair report above in your question. And try fsck on your ext4 partition. https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789  And check Windows fast start up is off. https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Thanks for helping actually
When i did shutdown. system took longer than usual....It was displaying some warnings also which i ignored and used power switch.

Thanks for reminding - Here is the Boot-Repair report
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gw8ZzfdY7V/

I have not yet performed the fsck. I'll do it next

Comment: All partitions on sda are unknown. I might then check drive's SmartStatus. You can use gnome-Disks if Ubuntu or install it. You also have many duplicate UEFI boot entries. And one Windows entry 0000 that says it boots grub which you should not have. And Unknown device is typical of Acer where you have not set "trust". Remove UEFI entries: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228  Acer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217061/installation-on-acer-swift-5-freezes-no-partitions-shown & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702