# Can see my HDD in Windows but not from Linux live boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive, live-usb

I've just gotten a new laptop (Acer Aspire A315-56), where I can't see my HDD from a Linux live boot. When I'm opening GParted, it's only showing one disk and it's the USB Drive from where I've live booted it. My laptop came preinstalled with Windows 10 Home.

I've looked up Ask Ubuntu and similar forums, and according to the suggestions, I've tried out the following:

```
Set the SATA Mode to "AHCI" from "Optane without RAID"

Disabled Fast Boot from BIOS

Disabled Secure Boot

Disabled Fast Startup and Hibernate from Windows 10 Power Options
```

Unfortunately, none of those turned out to work for me.

As I'm not able to see the HDD from Linux, I'm not able to install it. Can anyone help me out with making the HDD visible from Linux? Using a Virtual Machine isn't really a solution.

Also, I've checked that upon hitting `sudo lshw` in the terminal, the SATA Controller shows up there. So, the SATA controller's driver is in the kernel.

Obviously, I'm live-booting Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Arka Bhai - I can tell you is that I purchased the same laptop in first week of August and trying all the things which you did in your post above. I am still unable to find a solution. However, good thing is that I made live 16 GB USB of various Linux distros in UEFI GPT scheme (Ubuntu, Manjaro, Mint and Solus) and installed each of them on separate 64 GB USB sticks with full installation. And I can tell you that this work Fine and you can store files, change settings and backgrounds without any problems and next time when you boot your settings and documents are intact. This way I choose my distros anytime I like. This is because I feel Dual Boot is not getting done on this laptop maybe due to proprietary encryption or internal locks placed by the default pre-installed OS W10 in my case. So I chose this method to do full installation on external USB sticks of adequate storage. You can choose more than 64 GB stick also. But keep in mind that it should be UEFI GPT scheme bootable only. I hope you will enjoy my way of solution which is close to dual boot. And again note that I have got the same laptop so don't worry to ask more. Bye.
Update - Also check whether the Disk Management in Windows shows that the Windows Recovery Partition is in the end of the disk. In my case it is in the end. I sometimes feel that this maybe one issue of not allowing anything in between or before the Recovery Partition. I don't know but seems something connected to it. Bye.

Comment: I've returned the laptop. I'll be opting for a different laptop. Thanks for your time, though.

Comment: That's good you have that option. But I really don't understand why this is a unique problem. Don't buy Acer I suggest. Maybe try first with Dell. They seem to have good support. But first check BIOS settings in the Dell store itself. If Legacy option is available then buy it. Otherwise it's a chance that Linux will recognise hard disk again or not. Bye.

Answer (score 0):

Arka Bhai. You can also refer my problem which I posted on this same issue in this link [Hard disk not detected during Dual boot installation on New Acer Aspire A315-56 laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264304/hard-disk-not-detected-during-dual-boot-installation-on-new-acer-aspire-a315-56)
I sometimes feel Linux does not have any answer to this problem and you would find that there are many unsolved issues lying out there in many Linux forums about same problem in variety of computers even with different manufacturers.  After getting exhausted I chose multiple bootable full installation USB stick option.
However, I will be much happier if you find a Dual boot solution here in forum or anywhere. In case you find it please post here so that others like me will be enlightened. Bye again.