# Whether unallocated space created after shrinking Windows 10 partition can be used for Kubuntu installation?

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu, gparted, unallocated

I have a triple boot Linux with Ubuntu and Deepin Linux OS with Windows 10 (preinstalled) in the new Dell Vostro 15 3590 laptop.  So I wanted to try with third Linux Kubuntu 20.04.  For this, I shrank the C volume in W10 by 65 GB approx for installing the Kubuntu distro.  However, after doing that, the installer is showing this as unallocated space in GParted / Partition Manager.  Whether this unallocated space can be used for installation or I will need to do something to make it usable.

[image: GParted screenshot image]

Comment: Unallocated space is perfect. What is the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: (K)Ubuntu installation should find the unallocated space and offer to install there. Please try it yourself. You can cancel installation if it does not work the way you want. If it does not work, then update the question. If it works, please delete the question.

Comment: Would use the something else option to make sure of installing in right partition.

Comment: You are showing two FAT32 partitions with esp flag. You should only have one with flags. You can have multiple FAT32 partitions if you want. I also use something else and on swap partition say do not use, so swap file is created. But then your / may need to be a bit larger.

Comment: @oldfred - I successfully installed 3 Linux distribution (Ubuntu, DeePin and MX) on this laptop with W10 preinstalled. I took 15 to 18 GB for root in all cases and 8GB for swap in each case and around 35 to 40 GB as home and slightly more than 1.5 GB for esp bootloader for all individually while installing. And the last one installed was MX Linux whose Grub is the one in command at start. And all working fine till now. Please let me know if there is anything more I should do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless hibernating, which is not recommended, you do not need large swap. And if not encrypted you can share swap (one per drive). Ubuntu now uses a 2GB swap file, unless swap partition found. And if you installed Ubuntu last it would add all swap partitions to fstab, which you would not want, not sure about others. I would have kept /home inside a bit larger / root) and used a larger data partition(s). Perhaps one Linux ext4 for Linux data and one NTFS for data you want to share with Windows. If not booting run Boot-Repair report & post link.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine installing it on an unallocated space. (labeled as "free space" in ubuntu installation)

**How to install (K)Ubuntu on free space (unallocated space)**

1. Boot from the Ubuntu or Kubuntu LiveUSB
2. Click "Install (K)Ubuntu"
3. Select your keyboard layout, region, etc.
4. Select "Something Else"
5. Select the free space and click the "+" Button.
6. Create a root partition in it. and other partiton like swap and home. (if you allocated enough space for the ubuntu install)
7. Then, Click "Install Now" and wait for it to install the OS.