# Grub2 just cycles the startup splash screen

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04

For the past couple of months, I have been trying to install 20.04 on an Acer laptop. (I am a complete noob at Linux) All I can get it to do is cycle repeatedly at the startup splash screen. (Inserting the Live CD USB it boots perfectly fine) I have tried using the grub boot repair program with no change. Using the legacy setting in BIOS results in "no bootable device found". Disabling secure boot makes no difference.

I'm just at my wits end. Do I need to try a different bootloader? Is there some trick that I'm just not aware of?

I should mention that originally I was trying to install it on a USB hard drive- I finally just installed it directly to the SSD in the computer, and it still does the same thing.

Comment: What model Acer? Most need you to enable "trust".  Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware? Acer Aspire 5 Model A515-54-5649  Intel Core i5-10210U Install Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702 Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot
Acer Swift 5 (2019) ctrl-s  in UEFI required to be able to change to AHCI mode.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217061/installation-on-acer-swift-5-freezes-no-partitions-shown

Comment: @oldfred thanks for the reply! I just looked into the bios and there were literally 100 boot files? I will study the links you provided and see if I can find something.

Comment: You need to remove duplicates. If UEFI entries, you may run out of NVRAM space, if too many. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228

Comment: To answer your previous question, yes I have done the steps to add a "trusted file" in the BIOS settings. I'm curious as to where these multiple entries are coming from. I think they are being created at the boot up screen (where it keeps cycling over and over)

Comment: It says "System Bootorder not found. Initializing defaults. Creating Boot Entry "Bootxxxx with label "ubuntu" for file "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi"

Comment: Well, I solved the problem. Is there a way to mark this as solved and provide a link to the answer that helped me?

Comment: You can post your own answer and a day later accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Following these instructions fixed my problem:

[Unable to install Ubuntu on Acer Aspire ES1-533](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862946/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-es1-533/876153#876153)

This helped me get rid of all the extra boot files:

https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/how-to-use-linux-efibootmgr-examples

I basically copied and pasted the delete command in a text editor, then pasted it into the terminal window. I was able to delete dozens of the entries at a time! Just be careful when you type in the hex codes cuz this will do some damage if you get things wrong.

Thanks again to @oldfred for the help!