# Hard disk not showing up in ubuntu 16,18,20, linux mint versions while installing on preinstalled acer laptop

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, laptop, acer

I bought a new laptop Acer Extensa 215-52 with predefined Windows 10 installed on it.

I tried to dual boot with ubuntu 16,18,20 and linux mint 20 version.
Some Bios settings are as searching on the internet to dual boot.

1. secure boot: disabled
2. fast boot : disabled
3. SATA mode : AHCI

Also I have reinstalled the window 10, but the hard disk partitions still not showing up. Its only showing up the USB partition as /dev/sda.

Its been 3 days searching for answers but no luck. Also asked this same question on ACER community. Here is the link: [Dual boot: Hard disk partitions not showing up on ubuntu installation](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/614025/dual-boot-hard-disk-partitions-not-showing-up-on-ubuntu-installation).

Also read  this user question seems same to my issue, but cant comment on that as my reputation is not sufficient for comment. So I have to create a new question. May be other might have faced this issue with same acer model laptop.

Please help me out on this.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried all answers from acer post and still can't see hard drive?  Have you tried burning ISO from another burning program.

Comment: Yes i tried most of all they say in group. I also tried RUFUS, make start disks utility, universal usb installer, etc to create the ISO.
Also used the GPT partition, and also left the un-allocated space through disk management.

Comment: Open gparted in the ubuntu installer and see what drives are there.

Comment: Its only my USB drive show up as /dev/sda and other /loop/0, /loop1 etc but no hard disk partitions.

Comment: In top right corner of gparted where it says sda, is there down/up pointer?  Gparted usually only shows one drive at a time.

Comment: Go into Windows and see what type of partitions are showing.  Basic or dynamic.

Comment: @crip659 I checked it's only one option. /dev/sda.  Also there is one unallocated space of more than 190gb in disk management in black color.

Comment: Did you install AHCI drivers into Windows? Otherwise change back, check Windows and then install AHCI drivers. You probably need to update UEFI and SSD firmware. And Acer typically has needed "trust" setting once Ubuntu is installed. And if new system only use 20.04.1. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217061/installation-on-acer-swift-5-freezes-no-partitions-shown
Acer Aspire 5 Model A515-54-5649  Intel Core i5-10210U Install Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702

Comment: @oldfred How to install AHCI drivers? I have WD machenical hard disk. Can you give me reference to update UEFI?  I will give it a try booting the windows in safe mode option.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems & 
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347 You need to go to the Acer support/drivers for your model system. It will have BIOS/UEFI updates and you compare your version to newest available. Usually also have instructions on site. Windows also can do it, but do not know Windows.

Comment: Just tried both option mentioned in the links. No luck. Only usb is showing no HDD partitions.

Comment: Has anybody face this issue with Acer laptops and resolved it. Please help.

Comment: I tried "closing the screen lid" for 3-5 sec and it displays the hard disk partitions. After that, I installed ubuntu 20.04 on it successfully and restart the system.
It shows the grub-like screen to ask the boot options
1 ubuntu
2. was something
3. Windows 10 boot manager
4 UEFI settings

I tried the windows 10 option to check if windows working. and it was working fine. 
Then tried with ubuntu option It displays errors about "initramfs" errors.

Answer (score 0):

Open GParted. if the nvram dimm isn't there go back into the BIOS. Second tab-hit Ctrl+S (secret mode) then switch RAID to AHCI. It makes the nvdimm disappear. IT seems to be the problem. I'm noticing another one, especially after win recommended firmware updates (don't, it'll reset everything). If you install Ubuntu (not Debian, Fedora untested) and press F2 or ask to UEFI access, the system hangs on the Acer logo and will not proceed. I have ran soft raid software. It tells me that the SSD that Linux is on is failing, but SMART indicates otherwise (everything is OK). I don't know.

Comment: For dual boot issue, I had to buy new SSD, move the Windows partition to the SSD then it shows all the partitions SSD and HDD on ubuntu installation. Please check all my findings here on this link : https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/614025/dual-boot-hard-disk-partitions-not-showing-up-on-ubuntu-installation Hope it will help others.