# Change BIOS options automatically with GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bios, ahci, rst

I have just set up a dualboot Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 on my Acer laptop.
The annoying thing with Acer is that the default installation of Windows uses RST with premium Optane while Linux cannot work with that and uses AHCI.
At the moment, each time I want to change my OS, I have to go to the BIOS to change this which is quite frustrating.

It might be a dumb question but is there a way to set up grub so that when I choose either Windows or Ubuntu it changes this BIOS parameter?

If not is there something that I can do (reinstalling Windows is not an option as it was installed when I bought my computer)

Thanks

Comment: You need to install the AHCI drivers into Windows, then change UEFI to AHCI. Acer Swift 5 (2019) ctrl-s  in UEFI required to be able to change to AHCI mode.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217061/installation-on-acer-swift-5-freezes-no-partitions-shown &  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems & 
But if you do a safe boot first to update Windows, then boot to UEFI/BIOS and change to AHCI and finally boot normally, it works
https://superuser.com/questions/1672500/ubuntu-installation-with-intel-rst?noredirect=1#comment2565531_1672500

Comment: This is a windows problem. When using 2 OSes you will need to accept the fact that you need to use tools and settings both OS can use. "It might be a dumb question but is there a way to set up grub so that when I choose either Windows or Ubuntu it changes this BIOS parameter?" No. "reinstalling Windows is not an option as it was installed when I bought my computer" That is not the correct idea. You create an install media, you create backups. You do not install a dual boot without a backup plan anyways.