# Where did ubuntu go after bios update?

Tags: boot

I just updated the bios in my Acer Swift SF314-57 (2019) from 1.07 to 1.18.  The system has an original Win10home installation, a Win10Pro installation, (both of which I am trying to avoid using) and a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS installation (that I am trying to get used to using).  I ran the update .exe file on the Win10home, then rebooted with shutdown /r /fw where I adjusted the following options to the way I believe they were before:

- F12 boot menu = enabled
- function key behavior = Fn
- fast boot = disabled
- secure boot = disabled
- boot priority = 1. ubuntu 2. windows boot manager

I am presented with the same boot options as before; however, when I try to boot into ubuntu I get stuck at the Mate logo and in ubuntu recovery mode it gives up waiting for the root file system device.  When I boot with my Gparted USB stick it does not see the hard drive and same if I boot from my ubuntu installation USB stick.  Windows still runs fine.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Did it also reset trust? Acer has the "trust" issue. You have to turn Secure Boot on & enable "trust" on the Ubuntu entry. Then you can turn Secure Boot back off. If you have set a UEFI password never forget it or reset to blank.

Comment: I don't quite understand this comment.  TPM is enabled, but I didn't encrypt the disk or anything like that.  How does one enable "trust" on the ubuntu entry?

Comment: Older, but if trust is issue still applies: https://askubuntu.com/questions/597213/bootable-device-not-found-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-uefi-on-acer & in step 35: http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot Acer Swift 5 (2019) ctrl-s  in UEFI required to be able to change to AHCI mode and other settings.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217061/installation-on-acer-swift-5-freezes-no-partitions-shown